# find values dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:
df1:

```
id  name   city   age  found_in_df2
2   john   ny     20
4   maria  lima   9
9   susan  cana   17
```

df2:

```
comment           question            response
i'm john          are you there       yes, i am
hello!            jajajajaja          go ahead!
please, go on     hello susan         no, i don't
maria             i'm 9 years         sure
```

I want to find values from column called 'name' from df1 that exist in any column in df2 (this value could be in any column and even inside a phrase). If the value is found, so I want to write 'yes' in column 'found_in_df2' of df1.
Someone could help me with that?

Comment: It matters the index of the rows? I mean you can find different kind of Susans and your column `found_in_df2` should be populated even if susan appears just once in the second df.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter! The idea is just to know if name from DF1 exists anywhere in DF2. It does not matter if in DF2 susan is, for example, three times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be as follows.

- Use [`df.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to turn `df2` into a `pd.Series` and combine with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).

```
df1['found_in_df2'] = df1.name.apply(lambda x: any(df2.stack().str.contains(x)))\
    .map({True:'yes',False:'no'})

print(df1)

   id   name  city  age found_in_df2
0   2   john    ny   20          yes
1   4  maria  lima    9          yes
2   9  susan  cana   17          yes
```

Answer (score 0):

The below seems to solve the problem

```
import pandas as pd

def find_value(data, phrase):
    for col in data.columns:
        if any(data[col].str.contains(phrase)):
            return 'yes'
    return 'no'


df1 = pd.DataFrame([[2, 'john', 'ny', 20], 
                    [4, 'maria', 'lima', 9], 
                    [9, 'susan', 'cana', 17]],
                   columns=['id', 'name', 'city', 'age'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([["i'm john", "are you there", "yes, i am"], 
                    ["hello!", "jajajajaja", "go ahead!"], 
                    ["please, go on", "hello susan", "no, i don't"],
                    ["maria", "i'm 9 years", "sure"]],
                   columns=['comment', 'question', 'response'])

df1['found_in_df2'] = df1.name.apply(lambda x: find_value(df2, x))
```